# Close connection without send response on Actix-web

Tags: rust, actix-web

I try to find a way not to answer to an unwanted request (assimilated to ddos) by closing the connection without let the client it be known. This way, the TIME-WAIT connection stack of the emitter device will grow until no new connection is possible anymore, while everything is fine on my side.

I did look in the actix.rs manual and the docs.rs documentation, but I did not find any way to close a connection without giving an answer, a body seems always required.
I actually have this function as default entry:

```
async fn defaultentry(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::build(StatusCode::from_u16(503).unwrap())
        .force_close()
        .finish()
}
```

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .default_service(
                web::get().to(defaultentry)
            )
    })
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call register a `on_connect` handler on the `HttpServer` to
shutdown the connection. As far as I know there is no way to do it from within a handler.

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .default_service(
                web::get().to(defaultentry)
            )
    })
    .on_connect(|c, _| {
        if true { // whatever you're looking for
            c.downcast_ref::<TcpStream>().unwrap().shutdown(Shutdown::Both).unwrap();
        }
    })
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was far from good practice.

For posteriority, ```TcpStream``` has not the ```.shutdown()``` method anymore, use ```<UnixDatagram>``` instead (1.22.0 when writing these line). 

```c.downcast_ref::<UnixDatagram>().unwrap().shutdown(Shutdown::Both).unwrap();```

Comment: Huh? Curious, I'm running rust 1.65 and it's `std::net::TcpStream` does have `.shutdown()`.

Comment: My bad, I was using the TcpStream Actix-web struct. You are right, it works well with ```std::net::TcpStream```.